# PHP sends GET instead of POST

Tags: php, post

I have to post some data, but the same adress have some GET and POST functions. My PHP is sending a GET instead of a POST.

```
$apiURL = 'https://myAPI.com.br/api';

$data = http_build_query(array('postdata' => 10));
$uriRequest = $apiURL.'/main';

$options = array(       
    "ssl"=>array(
    "verify_peer"=>false,
    "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
    'https' => array(
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => $data
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($uriRequest, false, $context);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    return var_dump($result);
}
return var_dump($result);
```

I know the ssl part it isnt safe, but it is just for prototyping purpose.

I cant get PHP to POST intestead of GET on the adress 'https://myAPI.com.br/api/main'.

Comment: How did you verify that this is being sent as a GET?

Comment: Can you try `'http' => array( ...`  instead of `https`? Judging from http://php.net/manual/de/function.stream-context-create.php#74795 - `https` is wrong.

Comment: @Xatenev , thats it! you're right. 

That resolved my problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: @ThiagoPachioni Cool. I have submitted an answer on this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from http://php.net/manual/de/function.stream-context-create.php#74795 the correct way to create a stream context for a `https` secured page is:

```
<?php
$context_options = array (
        'http' => array (
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header'=> "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
                . "Content-Length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n",
            'content' => $data
            )
        );
```

As you can see we are using `'http' => array...` instead of `https`.