# PHP file_get_contents sends GET instead of POST sometimes

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have a rare case and I need some help.

I have two domains (AA and BB) with exactly the same software. On this software I do a file_get_contents() to retrieve some data. See below the call:

```
        $data = ['1234'];
        $post = array( 'data' => $data );

        $jsonData = array(
            'origin' => $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],
            'lang' => $_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"],
            'post' => $post,
        );
        $jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);

        $response = file_get_contents( $url_to_call, null, stream_context_create(array(
            'http' => array(
                'protocol_version' => 1.1,
                'user_agent'       => 'My_Agent',
                'method'           => 'POST',
                'header'           => "Content-type: application/json\r\n".
                    "Connection: close\r\n" .
                    "Accept-language: en\r\n" .
                    "Accept: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT"]."\r\n" .
                    "Accept-encoding: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]."\r\n" .
                    "Content-length: " . strlen($jsonDataEncoded) . "\r\n",
                'content'          => $jsonDataEncoded,
            ),
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer'      => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
            ),
        )));
```

The $url_to_call is the third domain (CC). On CC I have a routing system which discriminates if requests are GET or POST. In this case I only accept POST requests.

Depending on the scenario file_get_contents() sends a GET instead a POST. I have made a draw to illustrate the scenarios. In braquets you have the some digits of the IP where the domains are hosted in each scenario, being 127 on localhost and 91 and 25 two VPSs:

[image: Scenarios]

After spending some hours studying the cases and looking for information I haven't found any suggestions. I have see this question: [PHP sends GET instead of POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53816054/php-sends-get-instead-of-post) but uses "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and this makes the question totally different because there is no preflight with this Content-type and other differences.

What I should look at to discover why I have this behaviour?.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd suspect there's a `Location` header being sent from one of the servers that triggers an HTTP redirection. If I recall correctly, PHP streams follow redirections by default.

Comment: Thanks Álvaro, how can I search for this Location header. Everything is under my control (no shared hostings) and I haven't set any Location header. The only redirection I have is in all hosted servers at cPanel level from http to https, but I'm sure the $url_to_call calls a https.

Comment: I think you can check `wrapper_data` from `stream_get_meta_data()`.

Comment: The more I study the usefulness of stream_get_meta_data() the less I understand this answer. I'm using file_get_contents, the call is rightly done but somehow in certain cases the request is received on the target server (CC) with changed headers, from POST to GET. Where this change is done is what I need, but I don't know how to trace this call. With stream_get_meta_data() I can check an open connection with fopen. Any example on how to use it with file_get_contents() or how to trace it?

Comment: My bad, I had incorrectly assumed you could feed `stream_get_meta_data()` with the stream context but I don't think that works. Instead, you can get all HTTP headers appended to a [magic local `$http_response_header` variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php). Print it after the request and look for `Location` headers.

Comment: Hi Álvaro, This is what I get:

Comment: The story told by your headers is exactly that: you make your POST request, then the server redirects to `https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/api/get_icons`, and your client follows the redirection (as GET). You need to figure out why `CC` does that.

Comment: Many thanks Álvaro. You nailed it. Te debo una birra.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I get after the request:

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
    [1] => Date: Wed, 18 Aug 2021 16:20:57 GMT
    [2] => Server: Apache
    [3] => Location: https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/api/get_icons
    [4] => Content-Length: 248
    [5] => Connection: close
    [6] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
    [7] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [8] => Date: Wed, 18 Aug 2021 16:20:57 GMT
    [9] => Server: Apache
    [10] => Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
    [11] => Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
    [12] => Pragma: no-cache
    [13] => Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=866aabcab06944ab954ac5feb1d081ba; path=/;SameSite=Strict;Secure=true
    [14] => Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    [15] => Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
    [16] => Access-Control-Max-Age: 600
    [17] => Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
    [18] => Upgrade: h2,h2c
    [19] => Connection: Upgrade, close
    [20] => Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
    [21] => Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
    [22] => Pragma: no-cache
    [23] => Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
    [24] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
)
```

Location is fine.

Comment: Location is exactly what the file_get_contents is pointing.

Comment: But this [0] => HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently is where the problem is. How can I search what is happening?

Comment: Sorted, Álvaro you nailed. It was the https redirection on cPanel.